# How to pass template template parameter to template class without the underlying template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Take, for example, the following code:

```
// Say I have this class defined in some other file
class Foo;

// This class will act as a wrapper for an integer map
// to function pointers, which will create type TFoo objects
// depending on the given input (in this case a "const char*"
template<class TFoo>
struct Bar
{
    typedef TFoo foo_t;
    typedef TFoo (*get_foo_f_t)(const char*);
    typedef std::unordered_map<int, get_foo_f_t> foo_handler_map_t;

    Bar(const foo_handler_map_t& handlers)
        : handlers_(handlers)
    {
    }
    ~Bar()
    {
    }

    const foo_handler_map_t& handlers_;
};

// Now, this class will receive an _object_ of type
// "const Bar<T>&", which will have an already initialized
// map of integers to function pointers, different
// functions will be called with different input values
// via the public method, "action()".
template<class TFoo, const Bar<TFoo>& CBar>
class Quux
{
    public:
        Quux()
            : bar_(CBar)
        {
        }
        ~Quux()
        {
        }

        TFoo action(int a, const char* x)
        {
            auto it = this->bar_.handlers_.find(a);
            if (it == this->bar_.handlers_.end())
            {
                // no handler defined for int `a'
                return TFoo();
            }
            // i.e. CBar.handlers_[a](x)
            return it->second(x);
        }

    private:
        const Bar<TFoo>& bar_;
};


// Here is how the map of integers to function pointers
// will be initialized...
static std::unordered_map<int, Foo (*)(const char*)> handlers
{
    { 0, _hdl_0 }, // _hdl_* functions defined in different file
    { 1, _hdl_1 },
    { 2, _hdl_2 }
};
// And then passed to a "const Bar<T>" type object here
const Bar<Foo> bar (handlers);


int main()
{
    // --> HERE IS WHAT I WANT TO CHANGE <--
    Quux<decltype(bar)::foo_t, bar> quux;
    // -------------------------------------

    // Example (trivial) use of the 'quux' object
    std::cout << quux.action(0, "abc").baz() << std::endl;
    std::cout << quux.action(1, "def").baz() << std::endl;
    std::cout << quux.action(2, "ghi").baz() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that the 'Quux' class takes two template parameters - one that is also a template parameter for the 'Bar' class, and a reference to a template object of type `const Bar<T>`, where T is any class related to 'Foo'. I would like to be able to do the following instead:

```
Quux<bar> quux;
```

**Note:** 'bar' is an object of type `Bar<Foo>`, but it should also be able to be any `Bar<T>` type.

Is this possible? I was thinking that maybe something like below could be used as a quick workaround, but I can't figure out what to put in place of `/* ??? */`:

```
template<const Bar</* ??? */>& CBar>
using Nuff = Quux<decltype(CBar)::foo_t, CBar>

Nuff<bar> nuff;
```

**EDIT**

I'm passing in a reference to an object to 'Quux' as a template parameter because copying would be inefficient (I think), rather than making a copy of the entire `foo_handler_map_t` object. I just want to be able to have a bunch of objects of type `const Bar<T>` that are defined globally in some namespace, and to be able to initialize 'Quux' objects like so:

```
namespace blah
{
std::unordered_map<int, /* funcptr type 0 */> _funcmap_0 { ... }
std::unordered_map<int, /* funcptr type 1 */> _funcmap_1 { ... }
...

const Bar<Foo0> FSET0 (_funcmap_0);
const Bar<Foo1> FSET1 (_funcmap_1);
...
}

int main()
{
    Quux<blah::FSET0> a;
    Quux<blah::FSET1> b;

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

...And I do NOT want to pass it as a constructor argument.

Comment: What's this `template<class TFoo, const Bar<TFoo>& CBar>`? Since you indicate it compiles I guess it's valid just like a pointer to some extern object.  But what's the purpose here, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It would be nice if you can reduce your example a lot. Please provide the minimal code we need to catch your question!

Comment: This is not possible in current C++, will be possible once [n4469](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4469.html) is adopted.

Comment: @n.m. It was adopted for C++17 as [P0127R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html).

Comment: @bogdan excellent news

Comment: re `Quux`: You realise, of course, that passing the reference as a template argument causes an entirely different type to be instantiated for each reference passed in? Is that _really_ what you want? And if so: why?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I want to pass in `const Bar<TFoo>& CBar` just like I would be able to pass in a `size_t` value into a template like `template<size_t N> class ExampleClass { ... }`

Comment: @underscore_d Sorry, I'm new to C++, coming from a C background. What do you mean a new type is instantiated for each reference? Even if I pass in the same reference to two different template objects of type `Quux`? I just want `Quux` to be flexible enough to accept any object of type `const Bar<T>`, but I don't want it to be inefficient, which I think would be the case if it was being copied, rather than passed as reference.

Comment: @jinscoe123 If you just read a little more about templates, you'll see all good guides explain: Each combination of template arguments creates a distinct type, which must be separately instantiated in terms of member functions and static variables. (_Unless_ a _very_ clever compiler can detect and merge functions - unlikely.) Each different reference necessarily creates a different combination. Sure, you should pass by reference - but **not** as a template argument. That's adding plenty inefficiency, which you say you're trying to avoid - and inflexibility, to boot. Pass it to the constructor.

Comment: @jinscoe123 More broadly, I find it very difficult to think of a situation in which `template`ing on a reference/pointer would be useful. To me, it's wasteful and redundant when you're already storing the reference in the object - which you are. It might be needed for very low-level classes that cannot have their size changed, in which the reference must then be 'baked into' the instantiated member functions' code, in order to avoid residing as a member variable. Seeing as I assume the latter doesn't reflect your case, again, you probably don't want to do it. Or if you do, please elaborate why

Comment: @jinscoe123 And to be clear, even in the subset of cases where you pass the same reference, I can still see no reason to do so via a template argument here. The constructor can and should handle this. Just remove the argument from the `template` declaration into `Quux(const Bar<TFoo>& CBar)`. Re `...And I do NOT want to pass it as a constructor argument.`: If you mean the reference, you should! If you mean the template argument to the constructor, then until C++17, the grammar says you must - but **rahnema1** shows a nice workaround to avoid repeating the type by using a 'make' helper function

Comment: @underscore_d Ah okay, then yes, I will pass it to the constructor. How do I mark your comment as my answer?

Comment: @underscore_d I could just as easily pass it as a constructor argument, but I thought it would look better as a template argument... Just some unnecessary syntactic sugar I guess lol

Comment: @jinscoe123 We can't mark comments as answers. Anyway, I think **rahnema1** was already on the right track, although I'm providing more detail... possibly more than anyone wanted. ;-) So, I'm not sure I have much more to add, even once I found time to convert it to a neat answer. I would suggest checking their answer and seeing whether it achieves the kind of tidy syntax you want. Now that they've edited it to reflect the semantics of your class (rather than a simplified example), I think it will.

Comment: @underscore_d Okay, I will mark his/her answer as the answer to my question then.

Comment: @jinscoe123 Great. Also, keep an eye out for C++17, since as I mentioned in my comment to their answer, it adds the presently missing ability to deduce class template arguments from calls to their constructors. I can't wait to get rid of all the redundant `make_*()` helper functions this currently necessitates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are very useful. However, if you wish to reduce the number of template arguments, you can pass the `CBar` as an argument to the constructor:

```
template<class TFoo>
class Quux
{
public:
    Quux(const Bar<TFoo>& CBar)
        : bar_(CBar)
    {}

    ~Quux()
    {}

    TFoo action(int a, const char* x)
    {
        auto it = this->bar_.handlers_.find(a);
        if (it == this->bar_.handlers_.end())
        {
        return TFoo();
        }
        return it->second(x);
    }

private:
    const Bar<TFoo>& bar_;
};
```

And define a function to create an instance of `Quux`:

```
template <typename TFoo>
auto make_Quux(const Bar<TFoo>& bar)
{
    return Quux<TFoo>(bar);
}
```

Then in `main()`, you can use `make_Quux()`:

```
int main()
{
    auto quux = make_Quux(bar);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I don't see why someone would use a template argument for the reference, thus instantiating an entirely different type for each reference passed in... However, your example changes the semantics of the class. You should probably edit it to actually reflect what the OP is doing, i.e. retaining the 1st template argument and things drawing on it. Also, note that in C++17, `make_*` functions will become unnecessary as constructors will become able to indicate template arguments of their classes (as functions currently can).